# Twist short story about first man on the moon

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Google hasn’t been helpful in identifying this short story.  It’s about a man from a society dominated by females believing he’s the first man on the moon.  He stumbles across the Apollo 11 landing site but has no idea what it is.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This question is a bit light on details; you should check out the [suggestions for story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall any additional information you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: Poul Anderson's The Light (1957) has astronauts finding Da Vinci's landing site on the moon.